# Button after form fieldset

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml, adminform, cms-block

I want to put a button after fieldset legend as shown in fig.

I have tried the code below to achieve this but that not works.

how can I do this..?

[image]

```
$fieldset = $form->addFieldset('custom_fieldset', array(
                                   'legend'=>Mage::helper('cms')->__('Custom Block'),
                                   'after_element_html' => '<button type="button" onclick="alert(\'click me!!\')">click</button>',
                                   ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should work for you:

```
$fieldset->setHeaderBar('<button type="button" onclick="alert(\'click me!!\')">click</button>');
```

Just call it after you create your fieldset.

You may also use api to create button code itself:

```
$button = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
    ->setData(array(
        'label'   => 'My Button',
        'onclick' => 'return false;',
        'class'   => 'some-class',
    ));
$button->setName('some_button');

$fieldset->setHeaderBar($button->toHtml());
```